# Next on click image gallery setup

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a three select menu thats bind each other according to JSON data that comes from my controller.

```
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="selManga" ng-options="manga.seri for manga in mangas">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Manga</option>
    <option></option>
</select>
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="selChapter" ng-options="chapter.klasor for chapter in selManga.randomword">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Chapter</option>
    <option></option>
</select>
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="selPage">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Page</option>
    <option ng-repeat="page in selChapter.yol" value="{{page}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
</select>

<a><img ng-src="/{{selPage}}"></a>
```

Javascript:

```
.factory('MMG', function($http){
 var fveg= {};
 var url = 'http://api.mangayurdu.com/manga?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
 fveg.adlar = $http.jsonp(url);
 return fveg;
 })

.controller('nbgCtrl',function  ($scope, MMG, $stateParams) {

    MMG.adlar.success(function(loHemen) {
    $scope.mangas = loHemen;
});
```

Now what i want is when you click on the opening image it has to load next image and so on. And if its possible when you click on the last image of chapter 788 it has to load chapter 789. How can i achieve this?

Here is my jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Nasuh/zn85oonk/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn85oonk/9/)**

```
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="selManga" ng-options="manga.title for manga in mangas">
    <option value="">Select a Manga</option>
</select>
<select ng-show="selManga" class="browser-default" ng-model="selChapter" ng-options="+idx as chapter.title for (idx, chapter) in selManga.chapters">
    <option value="">Chapter</option>
</select>
<select ng-show="selManga.chapters[selChapter].pages" class="browser-default" ng-model="selPage" ng-options="+idx as (+idx + 1) for (idx, page) in selManga.chapters[selChapter].pages">
    <option value="">Page</option>
</select>
<img ng-src="{{selManga.chapters[selChapter].pages[selPage]}}" ng-click="next(selManga, selChapter, selPage)">
```

Changes to what you make:

- Removed empty `<option></option>`
- Removed `disabled selected`. If you want to select a value, set the variable binded to `ng-model`
- Moved the image element binded to `selPage` under the controller
- Select chapter and page index instead of the url
- Added `ng-click` and a `next(manga, chapter, page) function`
- Remove the two watchers

Comment: Thanks but I ask to click to those images. When click current one it has to load next  one. Could you update it that way?

Comment: I am really appreciate for your afford man. But manga pictures has to be clickable, readers want it that way. Could you put `<img/>` tag inside of `<a/>` tag?

Comment: Ahem. Manga pictures ARE clickable. If you mean they don't have the pointer cursor, then this is a styling matter: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn85oonk/10/). This is by the way out of the scope of the question.

Comment: You're the best man. Onyl one thing i gonna ask. Those select menus hasto shown from start. All three of them.